# Добавление класса дочерним элементам

Tags: jquery, css

При наведении на блок `#about-me-item` верхний квадрат должен менять `background-color`, `h3` и `<p>Learn More</p>` должны менять цвет на синий.

Попробовал сделать через добавление класса, но тогда он добавляется только у квадрата. Может что-то неправильно прописал в скрипте, т.к. с jQuery не знаком.
Может кто-то подскажет как такое можно реализовать на чистом CSS?

```js
$('#about-me-item').hover(
  function() {
    $(this).children('#about-me-item-top').addClass('bg-blue')
  },
  function() {
    $(this).children('#about-me-item-top').removeClass('bg-blue')
  },
  function() {
    $(this).children('h3').addClass('h3-blue')
  },
  function() {
    $(this).children('h3').removeClass('h3-blue')
  }
);
```

```css
.about-me-item-top {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  width: 55px;
  height: 55px;
}
.bg-blue {
  background-color: #196fc0;
}
.h3-blue {
  color: #196fc0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="about-me-item" class="about-me-item">
  <div class="about-me-item-top" id="about-me-item-top"></div>
  <h3>Achievements</h3>
  <p>Facilisis nulla de quam sed ipsum sed urab itur nulla odio de bibendum sit amd facs ed lobortis ld justo donec eso</p>
  <p>Learn More</p>
</div>
```

[пример на cssdeck.com](http://cssdeck.com/labs/collab/rkaun64i)

Comment: какая версия jQuery используется?

Comment: пробовал на 1.8.0 и на 1.11.1

Comment: Приведенный код не работает из-за того, что метод `hover` принимает всего **два** параметра, остальные переданные просто игнорируются

Comment: Можно ли задать как-то всё в одной функции?

Comment: Добавил ответ с одной функцией

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.about-me-item-top {
  border: 1px solid #DDD;
  width: 55px;
  height: 55px;
}

#about-me-item:hover .about-me-item-top  { background-color: #196fc0; }
#about-me-item:hover a { color: #196fc0; }
a { cursor: pointer; }
```

```html
<div id="about-me-item" class="about-me-item">
  <div class="about-me-item-top" id="about-me-item-top"></div>
  <h3>Achievements</h3>
  
  <p>Facilisis nulla de quam sed ipsum sed urab itur nulla odio de
     bibendum sit amd facs ed lobortis ld justo donec eso</p>
  <a>Learn More</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Полагаю `Learn More` – ссылка, сменил тег на `<a>`

Answer (score 2):

Приведенный код не работает из-за того, что метод [`hover`](https://api.jquery.com/hover/) принимает всего два параметра, остальные переданные просто игнорируются

Так как содержимое обработчика довольно простое, можно обойтись одним параметром который будет вызываться и в случае наведения и в случае ухода с элемента, в котором просто вызывать [`toggleClass`](https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/#toggleClass1)

```js
$('#about-me-item').hover(function() {
  $(this).children('#about-me-item-top').toggleClass('bg-blue');
  $(this).children('h3').toggleClass('h3-blue');
});
```

```css
.about-me-item-top {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  width: 55px;
  height: 55px;
}
.bg-blue {
  background-color: #196fc0;
}
.h3-blue {
  color: #196fc0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="about-me-item" class="about-me-item">
  <div class="about-me-item-top" id="about-me-item-top">
  </div>
  <h3>Achievements</h3>
  <p>Facilisis nulla de quam sed ipsum sed urab itur nulla odio de bibendum sit amd facs ed lobortis ld justo donec eso</p>
  <p>Learn More</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#about-me-item:hover .about-me-item-top{
   background-color: blue;
}

#about-me-item:hover h3,
#about-me-item:hover p{
   color: red;
}
```

Думаю, вам просто нужны эти стили?

Comment: отлично, подредактировал немного под себя. Спасибо